# Как вывести в переменную JS ответ от Yandex Translation API?

Tags: javascript, json, api

Всем привет.
Есть необходимость переводить отдельные строки с одного языка на другой.
Нагуглил решение через Yandex Translation API

```
async function yandexTranslate(text, language) {
return (await fetch('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key='
        + "trnsl.1.1.20130922T110455Z.4a9208e68c61a760.f819c1db302ba637c2bea1befa4db9f784e9fbb8"
        + '&lang='
        + encodeURIComponent(language)
        + '&text='
        + encodeURIComponent(text))
    .then(response => response.json())).text;}
```

Остался только один вопрос: как результат записать в переменную? Необходимо получить только строку с переводом.
Всем спасибо!

Comment: ?key=  Выделен только для тебя и не постоянен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю что там выдает яндекс. Но правильнее будет использовать следующий код

```
async function yandexTranslate(text, language) {
    const res = await fetch('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key='
        + "trnsl.1.1.20130922T110455Z.4a9208e68c61a760.f819c1db302ba637c2bea1befa4db9f784e9fbb8"
        + '&lang='
        + encodeURIComponent(language)
        + '&text='
        + encodeURIComponent(text))
    const json = await res.json()
    return json
}

yandexTranslate('hello', 'ru')
    .then(result => console.log(result))
```